# "image" stylesheet property does not display the image when appplied on a QToolButton

Tags: image, qt, icons, qtstylesheets, qtoolbutton

When I set a `QToolButton`'s image to a resource file in stylesheet, it fails — no icon image showed after running:

```css
QToolButton#example[state="checked"]
{
  image: url(:/images/checked.png);
}
```

However, If I modify a bit of the stylesheet like the following (the rest is the same):

```css
QToolButton#example[state="checked"]
{
  qproperty-icon: url(:/images/checked.png);
}
```

It succeeds.

Is the `image` property not supported? That is the example case from the official site. Or did I just misuse it?

Answer (score 0):

[`image`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties) property is supported, however, the documentation says (my emphasis):

> This property is for **subcontrols only**–we don't support it for other elements.

It seems to work for a QPushButton under KDE, but that is not a general rule. Using that combination is to be avoided based on what documentation mentions.

Also, from [QToolButton's documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbutton.html#details) (my emphasis):

> A tool button is a special button that provides quick-access to specific commands or options. As opposed to a normal command button, a tool button usually doesn't show a text label, but ***shows an icon*** instead.
>
> ...
> ***A tool button's icon is set as QIcon***.
>
> ...
> The button's look and ***dimension is adjustable with setToolButtonStyle() and setIconSize()***.

A QToolButton is meant to have an icon, not a background image. You can see how many methods it has about customizing its icon, and how its size is based on that.

Also, all of its [styles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ToolButtonStyle-enum) allow it to either have an icon, text, or both.

So trying to use:

```css
image: url(:/images/checked.png);
```

as its stylesheet, does not work, and should not work for anything other than [sub-controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-sub-controls).

As a guess, this behavior might be caused by the fact that the `image` property sets the button's size implicitly, because if you use `background-image`, it will work, but only if you set `height` and `width` to the used image's size.

So don't use `image`, and instead, use `qproperty-icon` as you've already figured out.